# Installing Pythonnet package on MacOS v12.4

Tags: python.net, macos-monterey

Has anyone installed Pythonnet on Python 3.10.0 (was pre-installed with Mac OS)? When I try to install Pythonnet through PIP, it complains that there is some issue with the package, and not with PIP!! After searching a bit on Google , I found that Pythonnet is currently not supported on Python 3.10.

So the next step was to install an older version (supported) of Python e.g. 3.7 on Mac and then make it the default Python environment. However, even after using the right set of commands, I'm unable to do switch from 3.10 to 3.7.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mieqI.png)

Can someone please tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please post as text not screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing a preview with `--pre` pip parameter. Python.NET 3.0.0 is currently in preview and is about to be released, it supports Python 3.10.